# Updating 10,000 records - what is the best way

Tags: python-2.7

I need to update 10,000 records and am wondering what is the quickest way, this is what I am doing currently

I get all the records I need to update, a big list of sku's.  I then loop through that list and update them.  In the below

in_both is my list of skus
I loop through, get the reference in ShopReconciliation and update

```
for line_item, sku enumerate(in_both):
    got_products = ShopReconciliation.objects.filter(sku=sku, run_id=self.reconciliation_id)
    for got_product in got_products:
        got_product.in_es = True
        got_product.save()
```

This works, but strike me it isn't very quick.  I could have 60k records

Is there a better way with so many records

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`cursor.executemany` is supported by most libraries like **cx_Oracle** or **pyodbc**. May check the database and data access library for availability of the function.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used transaction.atomic (with the With)

That seemed to work, I just need to be careful if an error occurs before the commit